# Making a function more concise in R

Tags: r, function

I was wondering if there is a way I could write the below function a bit more concisely?

```
Likelihood = function(x) dnorm(250, mean = x, sd = 10)*dnorm(265, mean = x, sd = 10)*dnorm(259, mean = x, sd = 10)
```

Comment: how long is `x` ?

Comment: @BenBolker, support goes from 220 to 300.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `dnorm` is vectorised:

```
Lik2 <- function(x) prod(dnorm(c(250, 265, 259), x, 10))
```

If `length(x)` can be `>1L`, you'll need to use an alternative version. Using base R:

```
Lik3 <- function(x) sapply(lapply(x, dnorm, x = c(250, 265, 259), 10), prod)
```

Using the `purrr` package:

```
Lik4 <- function(x) map_dbl(x, ~prod(dnorm(c(250, 265, 259), ., 10)))
```

However, I suspect your original version is more computationally efficient if `x` is not scalar.

Comment: What's the BUT?

Comment: Accepted and upvoted. BUT, if I want to use `Like.function = curve( Likelihood, ylab =  bquote(bolditalic('L'~(mu))), 
                       from = 220, to = 300, las = 1, lwd = 3, n = 1e+4, bty = 'n')` I can't use curve to plot it. BUT if I use my original version I can use `curve()`!

Comment: @parvinkarimi you hadn't specified that `x` could be a vector of length `>1L`. I've added two new versions that are vectorised for `x`.

Comment: Dear Nick, could I also use `sapply(lapply(...) )` (i.e., Lik3 in your response), to shorten the following: `Likelihood = function(x, y) dnorm(250, mean = x, sd = y)*dnorm(265, mean = x, sd = y)*dnorm(259, mean = x, sd = y)`?

Comment: Are `x` and `y` the same length? It would be easier to use `Map`, `mapply` or `purrr::map2_dbl`.